# Recent Apps won't show on Other User on Android 9

Tags: 9.0-pie, multi-user, recents-screen

I have an Android 9 phone and the Recent Apps button works just fine on my ADMIN (main) user, but ever since I created a new user, it doesn't show. I have to force quit my apps all the time to stop them from working in the background.

Whenever I press the little square, they're supposed to show and I like have ten apps open but it says No Recent Apps.

I've been looking for answers for some time, but, I can't find anything related.

Help?